# Could not load Jdbc Driver com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver

Tags: jdbc, mondrian, sqljdbc

After installing and configuring Pentaho Mondrian the below exception is thrown (complete stack trace)

I'm using SQL Server Driver 4.0

**com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException: Could not load Jdbc Driver com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver**

```
com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException: Could not load Jdbc Driver com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver
at com.tonbeller.jpivot.mondrian.MondrianModel.initialize(MondrianModel.java:455)
at com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapModelDecorator.initialize(OlapModelDecorator.java:132)
at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelProxy$MyState.initialize(OlapModelProxy.java:77)
at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.StackStateManager.initializeAndShow(StackStateManager.java:76)
at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelProxy.initializeAndShow(OlapModelProxy.java:160)
at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelTag.doEndTag(OlapModelTag.java:81)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.queries.colors_jsp._jspx_meth_jp_005fmondrianQuery_005f0(colors_jsp.java:127)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.queries.colors_jsp._jspService(colors_jsp.java:69)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
at com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:59)
at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspx_meth_wcf_005finclude_005f0(testpage_jsp.java:287)
at org.apache.jsp.testpage_jsp._jspService(testpage_jsp.java:127)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter$MyHandler.normalRequest(RequestFilter.java:139)
at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestSynchronizer.handleRequest(RequestSynchronizer.java:127)
at com.tonbeller.wcf.controller.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**Below is my mondrian.properties**

```
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.Use=true
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.Read=true
mondrian.native.topcount.enable=true
mondrian.native.filter.enable=true
mondrian.result.limit=50000

Provider=Mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=foodmart;Catalog=/WEB-INF/queries/FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
```

**Below is my web.xml**

```
<context-param>
<param-name>connectString</param-name>
<param-value>Provider=Mondrian;Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/foodmart;JdbcUser=sa;JdbcPassword=adminpassword; Catalog=/WEB-INF/queries/FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Below is my datasources.xml**

```
<DataSourceInfo>Provider=Mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;JdbcUser=sa;JdbcPassword=adminpassword;Catalog=/WEB-INF/queries/FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;    </DataSourceInfo>
<ProviderName>Mondrian</ProviderName>
<ProviderType>MDP</ProviderType>
```

I Already kept jdbc driver (jar file) in `\webapps\mondrian\WEB-INF\lib` folder

Answer (score 0):

Proper class name for MSSQL driver is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`. I suggest you search for text `com.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver` within your project and replace it with proper class name.

Also, as for me `jTDS` driver proved to work much better than MS own driver.

Comment: what would be the string for jTDS ??

Comment: in all the property files the string is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` only

Comment: @DhanishJose for jTDS use classname net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver and url jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]] as described here http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat

Comment: @DhanishJose and yet I presume it has to be somewhere either in property or xml files or hardcoded into jsp.